# animation with keyframes not working on firefox

Tags: html, css, animation, keyframe

This is nice, almost all css3 features works great on firefox and now I found this animation and is not working on firefox ?  on chrome or safari works great ? cand someone explain me why ?
ty.

```
ul.curent_buser{
    background:#fff !important; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: transparent;
    border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-animation: trans 0.3s;
       -moz-animation: trans 0.3s;
        -ms-animation: trans 0.3s;
         -o-animation: trans 0.3s;
            animation: trans 0.3s;
    }

@keyframes trans {from {margin-top: 15px;} to {margin-top: 25px;}}
@-moz-keyframes trans { from {margin-top: 15px;} to {margin-top: 25px;}}
@-webkit-keyframes trans {from {margin-top: 15px;} to {margin-top: 25px;}}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RwtHn/2940/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you've got a few problems besides the one you mentioned.

- In the html in your fiddle, you had `<a class="arrUp"></a>` right inside the `<ul>`.  The only child element type that can be inside the `<ul>` is`<li>`.  Changing this screwed up the arrow look, but I'm sure you can figure that out.  I would just make the image the background of the `<ul>` like you did with the parent `<li>`.
- Transition is a much better use for your drop down than animation.  This way you can have the animation work for both the close and open.  In your current code, even if the animation did work, when you closed the drop down you either had to create another animation or just have it disappear.
- The root of the problem was that Firefox wasn't running the animation before the change of the `display` type.  If you didn't change `display` type, the animation would work.

Here are my changes regarding transition.

Assuming you're going to have multiple items, so I changed all of them to be hidden instead of visisble.

```
#main > li > ul {
    visibility: hidden;     
}
```

Changed animation to transition and updated margin to have the initial value.

```
ul.curent_buser {
    background:#fff !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: transparent;
    border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: -10px; /* set to initial position */
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

I removed all of the animations and changed the focus to update margin and visibility.

```
#main li:focus ul {
    margin-top:25px;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RwtHn/2947/)

Comment: @ you are the greatest :) Thank you!